# D3 Persistent Path d expected number error during transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Sorry for the lengthy post, but I just wanted to share all of the trouble shooting and progress I made up until this point. This error has been persistent for over a week.

I have a line chart supplemented with three buttons representing three days of data. I have the buttons mapped to three `.txt` files and a `d3` event listener:

```
var fileMap = {
  'Day 1':'2018-05-17.txt',
  'Day 2':'2018-05-18.txt',
  'Day 3':'2018-05-19.txt'
}

d3.selectAll('.button').on('click', function(d) {
  var dayValue = this.innerHTML;
  var thisFile = fileMap[dayValue];
  createChart(thisFile);
});
```

So the idea is you can click the button and the graph will update itself. I kept running into trouble while implementing the `.transition()` call. I ended up using this, which works:

before calling the main `createGraph` function, I have a variable that counts how many times we create a graph:

```
var graphCount = 0;
```

Then within the scope of the `createGraph` function I have a counter:

```
graphCount +=1;
```

Then I have the logic necessary to draw the graph (initial state) or simply transition (if already drawn):

```
if (graphCount>1) {

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.date)}));
        yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.y2)}));

        d3.selectAll(".line")
          .data([data])
          .transition()   // change the line
          .duration(750)
          .attr("d", graphLine);

        d3.selectAll("g.y.axis").transition() // change the y axis
            .duration(750)
            .call(yAxis);
} else {
  svg.append('path')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')')
      .datum(data)
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', graphLine);


  var yAxisNodes = svg.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')')
      .call(yAxis);
}
```

Maybe it's not the most elegant way to handle update functionality. I admit it seems a little crude, but at least it does work.

**Red Flags:**

**X Axis:** First off, the x axis isn't visible in my graph, but that's by design. I have a tooltip that shows the x axis value, but I have omiited the tooltip for simplicity.

The X axis is a time dimension, the `.txt`s use unix time, which I convert using `new Date(((split[0]*300)+rawTime)*1000)`.  Meaning that instead of hour:minutes (as I originally wanted) all my `d.dates` are full fledged dates. Here is an example slice:

```
data[0]->Object->date: Thu May 17 2018 09:35:00 ….
```

I have a few `timeFormat` variables as well, but oddly when I try to call `d3.time.format("%H:%M")` the graph isn't drawn. So in my code they are not called. Since I don't need a visible x axis, I have let this go. The graph works fine when I don't use `timeFormat` and use the full fledged date from `new Date()`.

**The problem:** Whenever a button is clicked, the graph updates successfully -- new data is read from the respective `.txt` but for some reason I'm getting over 40 errors reading:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "12342542342352452, Nan".

Which makes no sense because the graph is plotted fine. As noted earlier, the unix dates have all been successfully parsed into javascript date objects. I passed the data to the console to examine just to be safe, and yes, it seems there are no parsing errors. All the dates and all the y axis values are there.

I'm not sure what to do, since a few button clicks will result in the log showing 100+ errors. I don't think that's good for browswer stability, but on the other hand, the graph **appears** to work just fine.

**Question:** Why am I getting 40+ errors in the log? My data set is around 80 observations long. I noticed it only throws errors during transitions. The initial graph creation doesn't have any errors.

Please, please make the errors go awayyyy.

I have a very minimal example here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/Zq9Yd6Hf7mlTlegMXiIG

**Hunches**

I also thought it could be the `xAxis` itself. But I passed
`d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.date`
 into the console log, and everything checked out again. Very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are due only to an empty last row in the txt files, giving you a last object like this in the arrays:

```
{y2: NaN, date: Wed May 16 2018 23:35:00}
```

Of course, you're not getting anywhere with that `NaN`.

**Solution**: remove those empty rows. After that your arrays have the correct number of objects (77 versus 78 in the running code you linked)

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/XdOcqsdCG3kXw8cvja9y?p=preview

---

PS: regarding that `graphCount` and your supposition...

> Maybe it's not the most elegant way to handle update functionality.

Yes, it's certainly not the best way. There is a much better approach: the famous **enter-update-exit** pattern! Get rid of that awkward counter and the `if...else` statement!

Comment: Wow thanks for bailing me out. I wonder why if it was only *one* row, why is the log showing 40+ errors? Is it looping or stuck over that row or something maybe?

Comment: In the plunker you linked it's showing just 1 error per click.